# How do I rounding DateTime to 6 characters after the second?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table called Test and I have a column called Date which is of Datetime datatype.
My Requirement is to get the values of the Date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.123456.

But I am getting values like:

```
Date
2011-03-09 11:35:03.890
```

So I changed the datatype of Date column to Datetime2 so Now I am getting the value like :

```
Date
2011-03-09 11:35:03.8900000
```

The problem is I want only 6 characters after that seconds but I am getting seven. Can anyone help me on this?

Example:

If the Date has value of 2011-03-07 11:35:03.1234567 then it should round of the value to

2011-03-07 11:35:03.1234570 and from that I want only six characters after that seconds so

I want some thing like this:

```
Date
2011-03-07 11:35:03.123457
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2 = '2011-03-07 11:35:03.1234567'

SELECT CAST(CAST (@d AS DATETIME2(6)) AS CHAR(26))
```

Returns

```
2011-03-07 11:35:03.123457
```

Comment: Does this expression round off the values?

Comment: @Sam - Yes I updated it to use your specific example rather than `getdate()`

Comment: @Richard - I had "results to text" switched on in SSMS and without that it truncated it to `2011-03-07 11:35:03.12`. Just switched to grid mode and it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the precision to get the rounding and then trucate it with by limitting the characters.  See the following example:

```
smalldatetime  2007-05-08 12:35:00
datetime       2007-05-08 12:35:29.123
datetime2      2007-05-08 12:35:29.1234567
datetimeoffset 2007-05-08 12:35:29.1234567 +12:15
```

Try:

```
CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15' AS datetime2(6)) AS CHAR(26)
```

Reference [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).